# How to get textbox value Inside <a></a> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html code:

```
<div class="viewPopup login-popup"  id="login-box">
     <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
     <h6 class="h6">Task Name</h5>
     <div class="info">
      <p class="name">Assigned to </p>
      <p class="cont1"> Kumar</p>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
      <ul>
      <li><p class="name">Task </p></li>
      <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum est ut dolor aliquam sit amet suscipit urna vehicula. Nunc dolor massa, viverra commodo gravida sed, sodales et metus. Maecenas lacinia facilisis semper. Pellentesque ac tellus lacus.</p></li>
      </ul>

     </div>
     <div class="info">
      <p class="name">Starting Date </p>
      <p class="cont1"> 19/12/2012</p>
     </div>

     <div class="info">
      <p class="name">Ending Date </p>
      <p class="cont1"> 22/12/2012</p>
     </div>
</div>

<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
    <input type="text" name="review_id" id="review_id" value="10" />
    <img src="images/eye.png" >
</a>
<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_id_txt" id="review_id_txt" value="10" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.login-window').click(function() {

                //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});
```

Here i want to get the text box value in that jquery code.

That means there have a textbox `review_id` which is included in the `<a></a>` tag.

So i want to get the textbox value by using this ` tag.

I know to this code:

```
$("#review_id").val();
```

But i actually get text box value based on that `<a>`.

How can i do this?

Is it possible?

EDIT:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){?>
<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_ids" id="review_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $i;?>" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>
```

This creates 5 `<a>`tags and 5 textboxes.Then how can i get the `review_ids` text box value...

Comment: did you have more no of <a> tags with textbox?

Comment: yes exact question..............

Comment: your tags are not matching `<h6 class="h6">Task Name</h5>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('a.login-window').click(function() {
          var valuet=   $(this).find("#review_id").val();
          alert(valuet);
});
</script>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_id" id="review_id" value="10" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>


<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_id" id="review_id" value="10" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>



<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_id" id="review_id" value="10" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>


<a href="#login-box" class="login-window" title="View">
                        <input type="text" name="review_id" id="review_id" value="10" />
                        <img src="images/eye.png" >
                   </a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why you have to increment the id?

Comment: if you want the dynamic id's for different purpose, then assign a staic class to the text box and get the value based on class..

Answer (score 1):

try just

```
$(".login-window").find("#review_id").val()
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4QLn/)

Answer (score 0):

you missed the sharp

```
$("#review_id").val();
```

Comment: @Kichu, not what? it's working for me too. check this one out. http://jsfiddle.net/zvk5A/